# Optimize neo4j cypher query with very large dataset

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize a cypher query on a very large dataset. I'm trying to find 2nd or 3rd degree friends in the same city.  My current cypher query is, which takes over 1 minute to run:

```
match (n:User {id: 123})-[:LIVES_IN]->()<-[:LIVES_IN]-(u:User), (n)-[:FRIENDS_WITH*2..3]-(u) WHERE u.age >= 20 AND u.age <= 36 return u limit 100
```

There are approximately 500K User nodes and 500M FRIENDS_WITH relationships.  I already have indexes on the id and age properties.  The query seems to be choking on the FRIENDS_WITH requirement.  Is there any way to think about this in a different way or optimize the cypher to make it real-time (i.e., max time 1-2 seconds)?

Here's the profile of the query:

[image: Imgur]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a test database that you could export to run cypher queries against?

Answer (score 0):

Create index on id property for label User:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(id)
```

See documentation for schema indexes for more information http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html

If that doesn't help add a result of [PROFILE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html) query and we might be able to help you more

```
PROFILE MATCH ... rest of your query
```

Also it might be worth trying rewriting the query the following way:

```
MATCH (n:User {id: 123})-[:LIVES_IN]->()<-[:LIVES_IN]-(u:User),
(n)-[:FRIENDS_WITH*2..3]-(u)
WHERE u.age >= 20 AND u.age <= 36 
return u limit 100
```

Comment: Thanks @frant.hartm.  I've updated the original question with the profile. I do already have the appopriate indexes.  Thanks!